# How to loop through multiple condition IF statement in C++

Tags: c++, if-statement

I am a newbie in programming and I wrote a piece of code that works, but I am interested in making it scalable.

The following code checks if a single word from a vector list matches with any of the words in another vector list.

```
            if (words[i] != dislike[0] && words[i] != dislike[1] && words[i] != dislike[2] && words[i] != dislike[3])  //check for disliked words
                cout << words[i] << '\n';
```

As visibile, the code does the job by iterating word by word, so if I were to change the nubmer of words in my second vector list, I will need to add it to the IF statement.

Is there a more optimal solution? I have been trying to figure this out for hours, however I had no luck.
Thanks.

P.S. Below is my full code.

```
int main()
{
    // words we dislike
    vector<string>dislike = { "broccoli", "coke", "potatoes", "water" };

    //take input from user
    vector<string> words;
    for (string temp; cin >> temp; ) // read whitespace-separated words
        words.push_back(temp); // put into vector

    //give output
    cout << "Number of words: " << words.size() << '\n';
    //sort(words); // DONT sort the words
    for (int i = 0; i<words.size(); ++i) //go through your words vector
    {
        if (i == 0 || words[i - 1] != words[i])//remove repeating words
        {           
            if (words[i] != dislike[0] && words[i] != dislike[1] && words[i] != dislike[2] && words[i] != dislike[3])  //check for dislike
                cout << words[i] << '\n';
            else
                cout << "BlEEP!\n";   //print if word is disliked*/
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Rather than assume a certain size for `dislike`, loop over it as well. After you've done that, simply can it and use `std::find`

Comment: Thank you. `std::find` is new to me, so I will research and try again.

Comment: Why not to use std::unique?

Answer (score 0):

What about this?
Adding another loop `for` that iterates throught all the `dislike` vector.

```
int main()
{
    // words we dislike
    vector<string>dislike = { "broccoli", "coke", "potatoes", "water" };

    //take input from user
    vector<string> words;
    for (string temp; cin >> temp; ) // read whitespace-separated words
        words.push_back(temp); // put into vector

    //give output
    cout << "Number of words: " << words.size() << '\n';
    //sort(words); // DONT sort the words
    for (int i = 0; i<words.size(); ++i) //go through your words vector
    {
        if (i == 0 || words[i - 1] != words[i])//remove repeating words
        {     
           for(int j=0;j<dislike.size();j++)
           {
              int count = 0;
              if (words[i] != dislike[j])count++;
              if(count  == dislike.size())cout << words[i] << '\n'; //check for dislike
              else
                cout << "BlEEP!\n";   //print if word is disliked*/
           }
        }
     }
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: While the principle of using nested loops is a reasonable way to solve this problem, the code you've provided doesn't match the code in the question. It would print `words[i]` for _each_ time that `words[i]` didn't match `dislike[j]`, whereas the original code prints `words[i]` if it doesn't match _any_ of the `dislike` words.

Comment: @davmac is correct. Capie, this is the code I tried myself and it did not work for the reasons described.

Comment: What about now? i just added a `count` variable that increments by 1 if `words[i] != dislike[j]`. If `count` is the same number as size of `dislike` then it prints out `words[i]`